# Magento: stopping the add to cart process in an observer?

Tags: magento-1.4, observers

I am observing an event which is fired when a product is added to the cart. This is the tutorial I used for it: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/

Now under some conditions I want to stop the process of adding the product to the cart. I tried throwing an exception, but this gives me the *There has been an error processing your request* error message. Checking the report that is created by Magento does not tell me anything. How else could I stop the adding process?

This is my code:

```
public function hookToAddToCartBefore($observer) {
    ...
    if(somecondition) {
         Mage::throwException('some message');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Features:

- Clear error message after
- Skips all "add to cart" code
- Redirect to the page of your choice after

After trying every imaginable thing out there to attempt to gracefully abort an "add to cart", I managed to combine pieces and discovered the flag FLAG_NO_DISPATCH by stepping through the source. Other attempts to change params or set redirect would be overwritten by some code further in the "add to cart" process.

```
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($store_product->getProductUrl());
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Sorry, the price of this product has been updated. Please, add to cart after reviewing the updated price.'));
    $observer->getControllerAction()->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
```

Instead of error, you can have a notice:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Sorry, this product is currently not available...');
```